# ngx-online-status is initally undefiend

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using ngx-online-status in order to get the online status of my application below is the relevant code.

Connection.service.ts

```
import { OnlineStatusService, OnlineStatusType } from 'ngx-online-status';
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ConnectionService {

   status!: OnlineStatusType;
   OnlineStatusType = OnlineStatusType;
   constructor(private onlineStatusService: OnlineStatusService){
      this.onlineStatusService.status.subscribe((status: OnlineStatusType) => {
      this.status =  status;

   }) 

  getOnlineStatus() {
   return this.status;
  }
}
```

On the initial call of getOnlineStatus() the value of status is undefined, it is only when I start alternating online/offline that the value is updated and working as should. I am looking at the link below and status is updated from the beginning.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-online-status?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

What am I missing?

Comment: Please provide complete code and not just fragments. Wherre is getOnlineStatus called?

Comment: Works as intended imo. Link does the same. If you look at source code https://github.com/VadimDez/ngx-online-status/blob/master/src/app/modules/online-status/online-status.service.ts it adds event listeners and only sets status on event emission. Set initial status to true and check before assignment would be my advice